# Save custom Coreplot Graph in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nsuserdefaults, core-plot

I'm trying to save a `NSMutableArray` of `Coreplot` Graphs in `NSUserDefault`. Here is my code

Save graphs:

```
NSData *encodedGraphs = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:graphArray];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:encodedGraphs forKey:@"graphs"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

load saved graphs:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *encodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"graphs"];
NSMutableArray *savedGraphs = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];
if (savedGraphs != nil) {
    graphArray = savedGraphs;
    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

When trying to load the saved graphs, I run into this error:

```
Assertion failure in -[UICGColor encodeWithCoder:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIColor.m:1439

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only RGBA or White color spaces are supported in this situation.'
```

Does any knows what is going wrong here? Thanks

Comment: that isnt an error... its just letting you know it is using a generic RGB profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a view that has a background image set by `UIColor colorWithPatternImage` breaking the encoding. I changed the background image to UIImage and it works now.